# In Keras, I want to save a trained model on my disk (Windows), but got error message "Invalid argument"?

Tags: python, keras

This is my code:

```py
sava_path = 'D:/5-PyCharm/unet-membrane/membrane/data/models/' + model_name
checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint(filepath=sava_path, monitor='binary_accuracy', verbose=1,
                             save_best_only=True, mode='max')
history = unet_model.fit(x=x_train, y=y_train, batch_size=batch_size, callbacks=[checkpoint],
                         validation_split=0.2, epochs=epochs, shuffle=False)
```

but got an error:

```
OSError: Unable to create file (unable to open file: name = 'D:/5-PyCharm/unet-membrane/membrane/data/models/Unet_membrane2019-09-28_09:50:25.h5', errno = 22, error message = 'Invalid argument', flags = 13, o_flags = 302)
```

If the `save_path` is `./membrane/data/models/unet_membrane.h5`, everything is ok.
The most important difference between the two is whether the path is preceded by a Windows disk character.
So, I want to ask whether there is a `D:` in `save_path` to cause this error?

Click this link to see my captured images:
[save successful](https://i.stack.imgur.com/chiAu.png), [got an error "invalid argument"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GBGUQ.png)

Comment: Because you're using `:` in the file name?

Comment: The successful image refers to a file named `unet_membrane.h5`, and the unsuccessful one refers to `Unet_membrane.h5`.  Perhaps the capital/lowercase `U` is the issue?

Comment: As @DanielMöller pointed out, your filename ends with `Unet_membrane2019-09-28_09:50:25.h5`, and Windows doesn't allow colons in filenames.

Comment: If I want to save a file to disk D, I must have a colon, which is inevitable.Such as: `D:\a.txt`. How to deal with it?

Comment: Choose another model name

Answer (score 0):

Choose another model name, or **try replacing '/' with '\\'**. This also occurred to me while creating the 'logs' folder from the Tensorboard callback.

The method that I mentioned helped me solve me issue.

Answer (score 0):

`Invalid argument` is caused by illegal character. The file name of Windows file can't include `\/:*?"<>|`. Your file name has the character `:`, please remove it.